# Unable to compute the area of region

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, geometry, mesh

For a set of data:

```
data = {{995.703, 0.672849}, {994.229, 0.685626}, {991.774, 
  0.693578}, {988.34, 0.688941}, {983.93, 0.693651}, {978.549, 
  0.704531}, {972.203, 0.731159}, {964.898, 0.73207}, {956.64, 
  0.728275}, {947.438, 0.721113}, {937.301, 0.730698}, {926.239, 
  0.751382}, {914.263, 0.776879}, {901.384, 0.781564}, {887.616, 
  0.783906}, {872.972, 0.780878}, {857.467, 0.786632}, {841.115, 
  0.805397}, {823.934, 0.812883}, {805.939, 0.811252}, {787.149, 
  0.80729}, {767.582, 0.818323}, {747.257, 0.823602}, {726.195, 
  0.830864}, {704.416, 0.846506}, {681.943, 0.842861}, {658.796, 
  0.835349}, {634.999, 0.840299}, {610.575, 0.842808}, {585.549, 
  0.851967}, {559.945, 0.868148}, {533.788, 0.876589}, {507.105, 
  0.864628}, {479.921, 0.857978}, {452.264, 0.858633}, {424.16, 
  0.860653}, {395.637, 0.861047}, {366.724, 0.869318}, {337.45, 
  0.881728}, {307.842, 0.89408}, {277.93, 0.899029}, {247.744, 
  0.894887}, {217.314, 0.885781}, {186.669, 0.880203}, {155.84, 
  0.881892}, {124.857, 0.886459}, {93.7509, 0.890874}, {62.5523, 
  0.891707}, {31.2919, 0.892137}, {0.000686499, 0.891543}, {-31.2906, 
  0.88872}, {-62.5509, 0.883872}, {-93.7495, 0.878692}, {-124.856, 
  0.8776}, {-155.839, 0.876955}, {-186.668, 0.87048}, {-217.313, 
  0.859657}, {-247.743, 0.84553}, {-277.929, 0.824158}, {-307.84, 
  0.789144}, {-337.448, 0.736637}, {-366.723, 0.666945}, {-395.636, 
  0.579511}, {-424.158, 0.476506}, {-452.262, 0.369389}, {-479.92, 
  0.279829}, {-507.104, 0.225048}, {-533.787, 0.206534}, {-559.944, 
  0.204395}, {-585.548, 0.193327}, {-610.574, 0.155006}, {-634.998, 
  0.0983544}, {-658.795, 0.0639628}, {-681.942, 0.0481704}, {-704.416,
   0.00999812}, {-726.194, -0.0540769}, {-747.256, -0.119798}, \
{-767.581, -0.15998}, {-787.148, -0.185997}, {-805.938, -0.21905}, \
{-823.933, -0.22143}, {-841.115, -0.234187}, {-857.466, -0.264621}, \
{-872.972, -0.272263}, {-887.616, -0.288497}, {-901.384, -0.306587}, \
{-914.262, -0.327461}, {-926.238, -0.352601}, {-937.3, -0.369635}, \
{-947.437, -0.385838}, {-956.639, -0.390443}, {-964.897, -0.421895}, \
{-972.203, -0.454918}, {-978.549, -0.454465}, {-983.93, -0.458914}, \
{-988.339, -0.478531}, {-991.774, -0.499764}, {-994.229, -0.512505}, \
{-995.703, -0.531943}, {-996.195, -0.536882}, {-995.703, -0.545775}, \
{-994.229, -0.572064}, {-991.774, -0.582752}, {-988.34, -0.599671}, \
{-983.93, -0.61244}, {-978.55, -0.615791}, {-972.203, -0.631241}, \
{-964.898, -0.641198}, {-956.64, -0.655771}, {-947.438, -0.671423}, \
{-937.301, -0.671268}, {-926.239, -0.681516}, {-914.263, -0.683255}, \
{-901.384, -0.700182}, {-887.616, -0.711777}, {-872.972, -0.719184}, \
{-857.467, -0.734338}, {-841.115, -0.744031}, {-823.934, -0.749785}, \
{-805.939, -0.753024}, {-787.149, -0.758666}, {-767.582, -0.77336}, \
{-747.257, -0.766347}, {-726.195, -0.760521}, {-704.417, -0.759134}, \
{-681.943, -0.770561}, {-658.796, -0.785752}, {-634.999, -0.80005}, \
{-610.575, -0.808609}, {-585.549, -0.814659}, {-559.945, -0.809641}, \
{-533.788, -0.804622}, {-507.105, -0.808619}, {-479.921, -0.814933}, \
{-452.264, -0.824676}, {-424.16, -0.83665}, {-395.637, -0.847347}, \
{-366.724, -0.851243}, {-337.45, -0.849248}, {-307.842, -0.845226}, \
{-277.93, -0.84505}, {-247.744, -0.848463}, {-217.314, -0.853465}, \
{-186.669, -0.856573}, {-155.84, -0.858592}, {-124.857, -0.859054}, \
{-93.7509, -0.862658}, {-62.5523, -0.87145}, {-31.292, -0.877667}, \
{-0.000741419, -0.881224}, {31.2905, -0.884006}, {62.5508, \
-0.884125}, {93.7495, -0.878148}, {124.856, -0.870916}, {155.839, \
-0.862404}, {186.668, -0.852149}, {217.312, -0.834875}, {247.743, \
-0.806898}, {277.929, -0.763839}, {307.84, -0.700117}, {337.448, \
-0.609422}, {366.723, -0.482247}, {395.636, -0.311266}, {424.158, \
-0.104396}, {452.262, 0.115888}, {479.92, 0.310883}, {507.104, 
  0.434027}, {533.787, 0.452608}, {559.944, 0.373157}, {585.548, 
  0.271737}, {610.574, 0.238174}, {634.998, 0.294259}, {658.795, 
  0.388007}, {681.942, 0.431574}, {704.416, 0.400651}, {726.194, 
  0.41664}, {747.256, 0.467887}, {767.581, 0.466103}, {787.148, 
  0.44411}, {805.938, 0.454418}, {823.933, 0.475323}, {841.115, 
  0.453061}, {857.466, 0.482326}, {872.972, 0.527791}, {887.616, 
  0.52652}, {901.384, 0.536385}, {914.262, 0.555416}, {926.238, 
  0.534647}, {937.3, 0.559003}, {947.437, 0.583895}, {956.639, 
  0.590674}, {964.897, 0.615758}, {972.203, 0.604291}, {978.549, 
  0.595058}, {983.93, 0.603277}, {988.339, 0.621725}, {991.774, 
  0.650783}, {994.229, 0.666861}, {995.703, 0.661105}, {996.195, 
  0.649131}, {995.703, 0.653303}, {994.229, 0.680834}, {991.774, 
  0.701984}, {988.34, 0.722025}, {983.93, 0.703909}, {978.55, 
  0.712565}, {972.203, 0.717324}, {964.898, 0.738665}, {956.64, 
  0.762189}, {947.438, 0.750662}, {937.301, 0.756154}, {926.239, 
  0.762045}, {914.263, 0.776795}, {901.384, 0.795037}, {887.616, 
  0.791569}, {872.973, 0.783403}, {857.467, 0.791338}, {841.115, 
  0.801706}, {823.934, 0.821618}, {805.939, 0.833832}, {787.149, 
  0.826512}, {767.582, 0.818115}, {747.257, 0.816921}, {726.195, 
  0.830269}, {704.417, 0.849679}, {681.943, 0.86529}, {658.796, 
  0.872935}, {634.999, 0.852952}, {610.575, 0.852018}, {585.549, 
  0.850589}, {559.945, 0.851081}, {533.789, 0.855915}, {507.105, 
  0.88198}, {479.921, 0.884893}, {452.264, 0.876493}, {424.16, 
  0.879354}, {395.637, 0.884601}, {366.725, 0.885976}, {337.45, 
  0.879266}, {307.842, 0.8827}};
```

When trying to calculate the area of the `Polygon` they define using the code

```
Area[Polygon[data]]
```

I get the following error

> Unable to compute the area region Polygon[...]`

But  `Graphics` shows the region just fine

```
Graphics[Polygon[data], AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to calculate the area?

Comment: Hm, why do you write the numbers as strings?

Comment: I hadn't realized that. It is the way Mathematica read them from a file and it could work with them whithout problems at least until now. I'll modify that. Maybe that's the reason of all this mess, but i had no problem with other Polygons or plots before.

Comment: Thanks Per. I tried your suggestion and changed it with NumberForm but it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Please post working code, i.e. get rid of the string formatting. Apart from that, your polygon self-intersects, which may be a reason for `Area`quitting on the job. For example `Area[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}]]` returns the same error.

Comment: No I haven't, but I will try and I'll tell you in a while. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @gpap Why would someone want to calculate the area of the convex hull when he is interested in the area itself?

Comment: @hairutan you're right, I missed the wiggle on the right hand side of the plotted data and thought it would not make a difference

Comment: It worked with ConvexHullArea so the problem may be the intersections and overlaps as suggested. Perhaps ConvexHullArea for farther applications is not very accurate but for my purpose, an estimation, it is enough. Thank you all. I will also read later if someone has more ideas and I will comment if I discovere something interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**---EDIT---**

@MichaelE2 is right in that it isn't the overlap (or at least not *just* the overlap) that is to blame. However, it's not *just* the scaling of the fast dimension either. You can see that if you resample the data by adding another point. Then `Area` calculates this just fine!

```
data2[n_] := Transpose[ArrayResample[#, n] & /@ Transpose[data]];
```

so

```
Area@Polygon[data2[Length[data] + 1]]

(* 2017.92 *)
```

however subsampling to n-1 points gives a rubbish result (still calculates the area without error though).

```
Area@Polygon[data2[Length[data] - 1]]

(* 8.71444 *)
```

I have no idea why this happens but the polygons in both the above cases look indistinguishable

```
With[{disp = Graphics[#, AspectRatio -> 1] &},
 Row[{
   disp@Polygon[data2[Length[data] - 1]],
   disp@Polygon[data2[Length[data] + 1]]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Also, playing with the `NIntegrate` method options of `Area` doesn't seem to have much effect either.

**---ORIGINAL ANSWER---**

I feel compelled to answer this because of my stupid comment :). The problem is with the curve folding back onto itself after a full cycle (around the last 200 points) so all you need to do forget about these 200 points and do what you tried originally:

```
Area[Polygon[data[[;; 200]]]]
(* 2044 *)
```

and gives a similar result if you drop the first 200 points:

```
Area[Polygon[data[[Length[data] - 200 ;;]]]]
(* 2050.41 *)
```

and the number 200 I worked out by putting it all in a manipulate and looking at where the overlap is:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[data[[;; n]],
  MeshStyle -> Red,
  PlotLabel -> n,
  ImageSize -> 600], {n, 1, Length[data], 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks gpap. You're right and it is related with what people  previously said. It is because of overlaps. Thank you everyone. By the way, Does anybody know if there's some special command to avoid this kind of problems?

Comment: I should comment more often if it leads to answers instead of comments :-))) +1

Comment: @halirutan yeah, definitely worked for me ;)

Answer (score 8):

The polygon is very thin.
If we scale the points so that the polygon is of good proportions `Area` works.

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Graphics[{Red, Polygon[pts]}],
  Graphics[{Red, Polygon[pts.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1000}]]}]}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Area[Polygon[pts.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1000}]]]/1000
(*  2018.48  *)
```

One might suppose that round-off error causes the failure of `Area`; however, `Area[Polygon[SetPrecision[pts, Infinity]]]` fails as well.  The reason behind the success of scaling, or even [gpap's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1079/gpap) workaround, eludes me.  It does not appear to be because of overlaps.

However, one should be aware of this issue with overlaps.  The region included by a polygon is computed by the even-odd rule.  Dropping the first 200 points (gpap's workaround) results in more area being included.  The area is correct for each polygon, so it is really a question of which polygon is correct.

Comment: But what about `Area[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]]`? This also fails...

Comment: @YvesKlett I hope it was clear that I don't know why it fails or succeeds.  So far `Area` fails if `RegionDimension` fails.  For your example `Area@DiscretizeGraphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]]` succeeds in approximating the area, but `DiscretizeGraphics` does not work in the OP's case (see user21's answer).  Discretizing is what happens with `Area[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1.}}]]` with a machine precision polygon.  But chasing down an internal bug might be futile.

Comment: @YvesKlett This difference suggests that your example and the OP's might be due to different bugs: `Region`RegionType[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]]` -> `"AtomicSymbolic"` and `Region`RegionType[Polygon[pts]]` -> `"LinearGraphics"`.  Different procedures are or might be used on different types.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a few more thoughts:

When you run this through `DiscretizeGraphics` you get a message about degenerate cells:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Polygon[data]];
MeshRegion::dgcell: "The cell Polygon[{39,40,39,41}] is degenerate."
```

As noted scaling helps:

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[Polygon[data.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1000}]]]
```

[image]

You can use the Finite Element mesher and specify what should and what should not be a region hole.

```
(em = NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[mr, "RegionHoles" -> None])["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

In this case nothing should be considered a region hole. (Leaving the "RegionHoles" option out, will produce the same as the `DiscretiveGraphics`)

You can then compute the area of the region without any holes. It really depends on what you want.

```
Area[MeshRegion[em]]/1000
2051.7452651013527`
```